# Editting a selected item using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am making a table with knockoutjs. I have a simple form that inserts the data into the table. The form is outside of the table.

I have 2 out of 3 tasks done. Inserting & deleting however I can't seem to get the selection working and populating the form with the selection.

I have a very basic example created within [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6LF/2/)

A short part of my viewmodel

```
  var viewModel = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
    self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (item) {
        return new ItemModel(item.itemAmount);
    }));
    self.inputItem = new ItemModel();
    self.addItem = function () {

        self.items.push(new ItemModel(self.inputItem.itemAmount()));
        console.log(ko.toJSON(self.items));
        self.inputItem.itemAmount("");
    };

    self.removeItem = function (item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    }.bind(this);

    self.editItem = function (item) {
        self.selectedItem(item);

    }.bind(this);


    self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (item) {
        return new ItemModel(item.itemAmount);
    }));

};
```

What do I need to do so when I call editItem() the textbox is populated with the value from the table?

I am sure this is basic stuff but I think I have spent to much time going around in circles trying to sort it myself

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly, you want to populate the input field with the selected item's itemAmount when you click 'Edit' and then update that row when you click 'Add' again?

Comment: Yes @Limescale thats what I am trying to do :)

Comment: Just as a side note: if you are using the closure technique ('var self = this' and using self inside methods), there should be no real gain from using the '.bind(this)' call on the methods themselves (though it does no damage either).

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6LF/4/) that demonstrates something close to what you're asking.  I'm not sure this is the best UX design, but this should demonstrate a way to handle updates.

The view has an edit template that it can display when the selectedItem is populated.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: selectedItem -->
    <input type="number" class="span1" min="1" data-bind="value: inputItem.itemAmount" />
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: selectedItem -->
    <input type="number" class="span1" min="1" data-bind="value: newItemAmount" />
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: updateItem">Update</button>
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: cancelUpdate">Cancel</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The view model has a new function called `updateItem`

```
    self.newItemAmount = ko.observable();
    self.updateItem = function(){
        selectedItem().itemAmount(newItemAmount());
        selectedItem(null);
    };
```